# Buildozer building to an Android app module not found

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

I am building an app with buildozer on Ubuntu.

I have successfully install an app on my Android phone and seen running.

But when it moves after a loading screen, it shuts off by itself with:

> ModuleNotFoundError.

Indicated not found name of modules are such as 'publicip', 'slacker' and 'idna' sometimes.

I have already enlisted them with ',' in buildozer.spec requirements.

```
Erorrs are shown as below:
08-24 18:32:48.164 15619 16088 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
08-24 18:32:48.164 15619 16088 I python  :    File "/usr/app/HanpoomApplication/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 27, in <module>
08-24 18:32:48.164 15619 16088 I python  :    File "/usr/app/HanpoomApplication/.buildozer/android/app/HanpoomLogisticsOperation/OrderSheet.py", line 3, in <module>
08-24 18:32:48.164 15619 16088 I python  :    File "/usr/app/HanpoomApplication/.buildozer/android/app/HanpoomLogisticsOperation/DB/DBAccess.py", line 3, in <module>
08-24 18:32:48.164 15619 16088 I python  :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
08-24 18:06:40.282  5364  5364 I display : HWC setVsyncEnabled = 0
08-24 18:06:40.301  9120  9718 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
08-24 18:06:40.302  9120  9718 I python  :    File "/usr/app/HanpoomApplication/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 27, in <module>
08-24 18:06:40.302  9120  9718 I python  :    File "/usr/app/HanpoomApplication/.buildozer/android/app/HanpoomLogisticsOperation/OrderSheet.py", line 2, in <module>
08-24 18:06:40.302  9120  9718 I python  :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'publicip'
08-24 18:06:40.302  9120  9718 I python  : Python for android ended.
08-24 18:06:40.346  9120  9718 I mali_winsys: delete_surface() [1080x2163] return
08-24 18:06:40.348  9120  9718 I mali_winsys: delete_surface() [1080x2400] return
08-24 18:06:40.474  5869  6123 W InputDispatcher: channel '75abee4 hp.logistics.op.hp_log_op/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9, fd=752
```